# Words describing purchasing of several items together

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

If somebody purchases several products with one payment, does the word "purchase" refer to the entire bundle or to each separate product?

Which word or collocation to use to denote the entire operation and which to the acquisition of individual items?

Comment: I doubt if any distinction is made. In accounting, if the items are entered into different accounts, then it is known as a *split transaction*.

Comment: The entire "bundle" can be called "a transaction". What is the name of each element?

Comment: A  purchase is a purchase, whether of a house, a car or 1,000 widgets.

Comment: The usual term is *item*. For commercial transactions, it can also be a *line* (in an order).

Comment: If you buy a thousand widgets, that can be one purchase. Line and item are accounting terms. That is something else.

Comment: On EBay and AliExpress even if you buy several products and pay for them as a whole they name it a purchase. If you buy one product, it is also a purchase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, a *purchase* normally refers to one payment for one or many *items*.

In this usage, *purchases* would refer to multiple payments for multiple items.

If I made an "installment purchase", e.g., paying 10% of the purchase price every month for 10 months, this would normally also be referred to as one, single *purchase*.

However, in a store, one might see a sign that says "Return your purchases to this desk".  In this case, for brevity, *purchases* is used to ambiguously refer to multiple payments or multiple items.

Answer (score 1):

*Purchase* is used for the action of buying something.

For example, "**a large number of videos currently available for purchase**", not *purchases*.

So if you buy more of one thing we'll use *purchase* instead of *purchases*?